# Logout button redirects uesr to the same page instead of logging user out

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, redirect, authentication

SheetTime.php is the main page. When the user goes to SheetTime.php, they are redirected to Login.php; if their login is successful there, they will then be directed to the actual content of the SheetTime.php.

The problem is with the logout button that I have. When the user clicks the logout button, they are always redirected to the SheetTime.php (page appears to just refresh) rather than being actually logged out and directed back to the Login.php. I have tried to change the location in Logout.php to Login.php and checked the URL, but I had the same result.

My theory to why this problem occurs is that because I set the location in Logout.php to the SheetTime.php, it goes back to Login.php, then back to SheetTime.php, etc. Pretty much seems to be caught in a loop here and I don't have much experiences with these kinds of loops.

When the user clicks the logout button, I want them to be logged out of the site and back to the login page so they can login to the site again. Any suggestions or do you see anything wrong with my code?

---

Logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["STYLE"]);
header("Location: SheetTime.php");
?>
```

SheetTime.php:

```
<?php  
session_start(); 
$user_name = $_SESSION['STYLE'];

//----------- Check if any user is currently logged in ---------------
if (!(isset($user_name) && $user_name!= '')) {
    header("Location: http://www.websitetotestfortest.edu/theTimePro/Login.php");
}else{

// (***there is other code in between***)

//------------- Logout Button (Terminates session) ------------------
echo "<br /><form action='Logout.php' method='post'>
    <input value='Log out' id='Submit' type='submit' /></td>               
    </form>";    
?>
```

Login.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['STYLE'] = phpCAS::getUser();
//$_SESSION['STYLE'] = $row['STYLE'];
$URL="http://www.websitetotestfortest.edu/theTimePro/SheetTime.php";
header ("Location: $URL");
?>
```

Comment: Well.. you're sending the user to Login.php and in Login.php you're sending the user to SheetTime.php. Also try changing your _if_ to this `if(!isset($user_name) && $user_name != '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['style']); //unset will work fine for a specifik session variable. If you want to get rid of all **your** active sessions for your domain use session_destroy();
session_destroy();
header("Location: Login.php");
exit;
?>
```

**SheetTime.php**

```
<?php  
session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['style']) || $_SESSION['style'] == '')){
     header("Location: http://www.websitetotestfortest.edu/theTimePro/Login.php");
     exit;
     }

//There's a valid session, so do things here.
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['doLogin'])){
    $db = new PDO("..."); //your database details
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM your_user_table WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");

    $statement->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['userName'], ':password' => $_POST['passwd']));
    $count = $statement->rowCount();

    if($count <= 0){
        header("Location: login.php?error"); //go here if there's an error... receive  it with if(isset($_GET['error'])){ echo 'your text';}    
        exit;
        }

       $row = $statement->fetch(); // if a result was found, fetchit
       $_SESSION['style'] = 'yourValue'; // define the session variable
       header("Location: Path-To-SheetTime.php");
       exit;
       }
?>

<form method="post" action="login.php">
    <!-- your login form -->
    <input type="text" name="userName"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="password" name="passwd"/>
     <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="doLogin" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

**Edit**
Furthermore, I do not see any reason why you declare $user_name with the value of your session variable. As in my example, you can perfectly fine verify the information in your session variable without declaring it to another variable. If $_SESSION['style'] is confusing (yes, it is!! :)) then maybe $_SESSION['user_name'] would make more sense.

**Edit2**
I added a database verification to the login. Check out PDO for more information here http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

As for the logout.. I assume that all those files are located on the same server and that you are indeed making sure that $_SESSION['style'] is written the same way all over. careful with caps.

When entering to the file the session **should be** unset. Please try to add session_destroy(); below the unset to make sure.

Adding a link to the logout is simply:

```
 <a href="the-path-to-logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Then logout will kill the active sessions and redirect you to login.php. Make sure all paths are correct.

Comment: Your examples and suggestions have been useful :) But I forgot to mention something important, the credentials for the user is pulled (successfully) from a DB. What would the approach be now? I have also tried what you posted for the Logout.php, but it was unsuccessful. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

First for a true logout I would recommend executing [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) then redirect. It will kill the session. Your session should be tested like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["STYLE"]))
{
   //Do Coding magic
}
else
{
   //Redirect to login page
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
//Test for valid login
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["STYLE"]))
{
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

}
else
{
    echo "<a href='login.php'>Login</a>";
}


?>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["STYLE"]="VALIDLOGIN";
 header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

logout.php:

```
<?php
     session_start();
     session_unset();
    header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Updated Spreadsheet.php:

```
<?php  
session_start(); 
//----------- Check if any user is currently logged in ---------------
if (!isset($_SESSION['STYLE'])) 
{
   echo "You are not logged in!<br>";
   echo "<a href='login.php'>Logout</a>";
}
else
{
    echo "You are logged in!<br>";
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This one is missing a ) on line 1

Comment: This doesn't work: <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION["STYLE"])) {
echo '<li><a href="Login.php">Login</a></li>';
} else {
echo '<li><a href="Logout.php">Log out</a></li>';
}
?>

Comment: See my updated example...i ran it locally. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

entiendoNull got the point : Login.php contains a header to SheetTime.php
You need to add a condition before this location header, in order to redirect only if a user is logged.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose that you have a table before this code

```
<br /><form action='Logout.php' method='post'>
    <input value='Log out' id='Submit' type='submit' /></td>               
</form>
```

change to this,

```
<br /><form action='Logout.php' method='post'>
    <input value='Log out' id='Submit' type='submit' />
</form>
</td>
```

by the way if is a url why you don't just use an `<a href="logout.php"></a>`